# how to allocate a block of memory in ANSI C and then ON their all bits

Tags: c

i just want to allocate a block of memory for **int type** and set all bits to  ON(1) after that how can i read that block of memory back.

Comment: There's no `bit` type in C. So you can't allocate a block of bits. You need to tell us whether you're allocating space for `int` or `char` or whatever. Otherwise we can't really provide any answers.

Comment: p = malloc(size); memset(p, 0xff, size); ?

Comment: Admittedly, before the language lawyers attack, my comment applies only if "CHAR_BIT=8".

Comment: @MatsPetersson: use `memset(p, ~0, size)` if you care about machines with `CHAR_BIT` > 8

Answer (score 0):

```
int *type = malloc(sizeof(int);
memset(type,~0,sizeof(int));
```

Reading back is nothing but,

```
int value = *type;
```

And `value` has all bits set to **1**.